# Use of App step - Does it give same result if person creating item in the list has owner permission?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, item-level-permissions, app-step

I have a list with item level permissions on. I am creating an item in this list and I have owner permissions. The workflow gets triggered and assigns a task to a person whose permissions are restricted by the item level permissions. **Right now** in the workflow task he does not get a link to the list item. Will adding an App step in the workflow help?

Comment: Hello @Amit, 1. Is the below answer helped you? 2. do you need any further clarification? if no, please mark the answer as accepted to close this question.Thanks! https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 2):

**App step** will allow the workflow to be authorized with its identity as a `Full Control` and **ignore** the current user permissions.

This is will ensure that the workflow will be executed successfully in case the current user has **no** permissions.

**So** It will help in case, you care about the person permission who initiate the workflow!! and I don't think it will hep in case, you care about the person permission who assigned to the task who restricted by the item level permissions.

For more details check [Workflow was Suspended with Unauthorized HTTP / Elevate Workflow permissions in SharePoint 2013](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/01/31/unauthorized-http-workflow-how-to-create-a-workflow-with-elevated-permissions-by-using-the-sharepoint-2013-workflow/)